# how to find distance between two areas in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, gis

hi all
i want to fin out distance between two places.  if i go from one place to another place by street by street the distance is vary and suppose i walk within a street the latitude and longitude may not be changed. so these method may not help me. is there any other way for calculating distance for my requirement  it whould be great to me.   please help me.

Comment: Difficult to understand what you mean by "these method is return distance in their way of find out the distance". Are you saying that distanceTo and distanceBetween are unreliable / inaccurate?

Comment: no not  that. i mean if i go within a street again and again the latitude and longitude may not be changed then how to calculate walk distance?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're attempting to do I would suggest figuring out if you can implement a pedometer (walking distance meter) using the accelerometer, combine that with the coarse location API and/or the fine location API and the compass you should be able to implement a pretty good location logger.

Other than that I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: please give example code or site . that would be great to me. thanks